# Is it context-free language?

Tags: context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

i have a problem with an exercise:

> L = {a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>m</sup> c<sup>p</sup> | 1 <= n <= m <= p}

Is it possible write a grammar for that exercise ?

I do not understand how to solve it :( please help me

Comment: (1) No this is **Not** Context Free Language, its actually context Sensitive Language, (2) Yes its possible to write context sensitive grammar for this.

Comment: what is the grammar of this language?

Answer (score 0):

The language meets the conditions of the context-free pumping lemma (for any string
in the language, you can choose to pump the **c**'s, and the resulting string remains
in the language), but that's not sufficient to prove that the language is context-free.

[Ogden's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogden%27s_lemma) should work, though. For a sufficiently long input string, you can choose
the "distinguished positions" to be all **a**'s, which forces the **a**'s to be pumped, and
eventually the string will be "pumped out of the language" when the number of **a**'s exceeds
the number of **b**'s or **c**'s.

Comment: Can you write the grammar of this Language, please ?

Comment: That sounds too much like real work, and for what purpose?  Consider the language of base-10 numerals that are divisible by three.  It's a regular set, therefore there exists a regular expression that recognizes it, but it is surprisingly complicated to write down, and doesn't give you any real insight into the properties of the language.  Grammars are good for understanding context-free languages, but when you get to the complexity level of context-sensitive and above, as in this case, you're probably better off trying to construct an appropriate automaton, rather than a grammar.